# Cancel choosing a file with file_picker_cross `FilePickerCross.pick`

Tags: flutter, dart, filepicker

I'm using [file_picker_cross](https://pub.dev/documentation/file_picker_cross/latest/file_picker_cross/FilePickerCross/FilePickerCross.html) for Android. I cannot find any way to cancel the file picker after calling `FilePickerCross.pick()`. The method replaces the full screen with the file picker dialog with no cancel button. I can tap the Android's back button a few times to get back to the app but this always throws an exception. I don't see anything in the documentation about canceling. I tried catching the exception but even that did not work. Below is a code snip of what I have tried.

```
try {
  FilePickerCross.pick().then((filePicker) {
    //            ^ NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'path' was called on null.
    if (filePicker == null) {return;}

    // do stuff with filePicker (exception is thrown before we get here.)
  });
} catch (e) {
  // we never get here even though an exception is thrown.
}
```

Comment: https://gitlab.com/testapp-system/file_picker_cross/-/issues/10

Answer (score 0):

`FilePickerCross.pick()` is deprecated. Use `FilePickerCross.importFromStorage()` instead.